# WriteMessageText() - example code compile error - error CS0103: The name 'Window' does not exist in the current context

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc, proximity

I'm trying to create an application using the NFC (proximity) API on Windows Phone 8. When I copy the example code from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.networking.proximity.proximitydevice.aspx), I get the following compile error...

```
error CS0103: The name 'Window' does not exist in the current context ...
```

This error is all over the internet and the common solution seems to be that it only works for native (or C++) code. However the documentation says that it works for managed or native code. How do I get the examples to work in my managed code?

Answer (score 1):

In order to gain access to the active `Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher` object, you simply need to request `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher`.

**ORIGINAL EXAMPLE CODE**

```
// Write a message to MessageBlock on the UI thread.
private Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher messageDispatcher =
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;
```

**CORRECTED CODE**

```
// Write a message to MessageBlock on the UI thread.
private Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher dispatcher =
    Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
```

The one small change makes all the examples work! Enjoy.